# iOS app connecting 3G using different network providers

Tags: ios, http, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, 3g

I am running an iOS application which communicates via 3G to some server. This server receives our HTTP requests and processes them, bla bla bla.
Recently, we started noticing that using different 3g providers to communicate with the server, the results are rather different.

For instance, in one of our cases we try to upload a zip file using this method:

```
+ (void) UploadZipImages:(NSString*)zipFilePath delegate:(UIViewController *)_delegate{

isLastUploadLocal = false;

NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddhhmmss"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

// Dictionary that holds post parameters. You can set your post parameters that your server accepts or programmed to accept.
NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.zip", dateString];

// the boundary string : a random string, that will not repeat in post data, to separate post data fields.
NSString *BoundaryConstant = @"----WebKitFormBoundary5FyPE45e6sSDdGnYP";

// string constant for the post parameter 'file'. My server uses this name: `file`. Your's may differ
NSString* FileParamConstant = @"file";

// the server url to which the image (or the media) is uploaded. Use your server url here
NSURL* requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://*************"];

NSMutableDictionary* _params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[_params setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",title] forKey:@"title"];
NSMutableDictionary* _params2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:1200];
[request setAllowsCellularAccess:YES];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setNetworkServiceType:NSURLNetworkServiceTypeDefault];

// set Content-Type in HTTP header
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", BoundaryConstant];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

// add params (all params are strings)
for (NSString *param in _params) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [_params objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

NSError *myError = nil;

NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:zipFilePath];
if (imageData) {
    NSLog(@"Temos imagem!!!!");
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"movie.zip\"\r\n", FileParamConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imageData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}else{
    NSLog(@"There was an error %@", myError);
}

// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// set the content-length
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];


// set URL
[request setURL:requestURL];

[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:_delegate];
```

}

This works fine using certain 3G internet providers (and it is fairly quick), but for another operators the request starts processing forever, until the timeout interval is reached... Which differences between 3G network providers can exist that can cause this problems?

THank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with the multipart/form-data message:

1. You are adding a CRLF after the image data which strictly belongs to the image data. The receiver may get confused (and probably will). Just omit that - and for any part, unless the server gets confused in body parts of type text which do not end with CRLF.
2. After the *last* part (your image data), a closing boundary-delimiter is required. You must add a

   ```
   [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--", BoundaryConstant]
                                dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   ```

#### Note:

1. You should also ensure that the first boundary-delimiter starts with a CRLF (this is probably already ensured due to NSURLConnection adding a CRLF after the message headers anyway). However, an additional first CRLF won't hurt which is then treated as "prologue" - which has no semantical meaning.
2. Strictly, you don't need a CRLF after the closing delimiter, but it won't hurt also - since this is treated as "epilogue" which has no semantical meaning.